# Cannot Set Navigation Bar Font in Swift on Latest Xcode Version

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navbar

The following code was running fine before updating to Xcode 6.1 to stay up with iOS 8.1:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {  
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Home"
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lobster 1.4", size: 34),  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
}
```

The issue is specifically in `NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lobster 1.4", size: 34)`

and the error I'm getting here is:

`! "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments"`

I found this original code on a different StackOverflow question and it was working as expected until this update (downloaded it yesterday). My font is indeed installed properly.

Should I be writing this code differently now, or is there an entirely new way in which I should set my Navigation Bar Font?

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Whoops. I figured this out on my own:

I needed an exclamation point following my declaration of the NSFontAttributeName as it requires a type "NSString!". Perhaps it only required an "NSString" before, but I have no issues now.

Working line:

```
NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lobster 1.4", size: 24)!
```

Working full code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {  
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Home"
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lobster 1.4", size: 34)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
}
```

Seems like a silly question now. Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `UIFont(name:` intializer as it is defined as

`init?(name fontName: String, size fontSize: CGFloat) -> UIFont`

[failable intializer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17) read more from link.So it is returning optional.You need to unwrap it as it require `AnyObject` not optional.

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lobster 1.4", size: 34)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Benji!!!

I changed it a bit and applied it to the appearance attribute of the navigation controller.

```
    var navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()

    navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 16)!,  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

Comment: In Swift 4.2: navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Chalkduster", size: 24.0)!,  NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

Answer (score 2):

It is better to declare your font as conditional , like this way :

```
 if let font = UIFont (name: "AdobeArabic-BoldItalic", size: 20) {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
        }
```

Doing this , makes sure that your font is already found , that I have installed new font , and when used it without conditional if , it issued an exception , of unwrapping an optional .

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 14)!]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

> Change **Small Title** *when layout scrolled down*

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {  
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Home"
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lobster 1.4", size: 34),  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
}
```

> Change **Large Title**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {  
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Home"
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Lobster 1.4", size: 34),  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
}
```